# Open Links on new tab upon link click JS (anchrome.js)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I am using the js plugin : https://github.com/alexcorvi/anchorme.js

This plugin detects linkable text and then converts them to links.

its been a couple of weeks and the developer has not got back to me, **does anyone know how to make it so they open in a new tab?**

or could you please help provide an alternative solution?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the following snippet from their official documentation.

You can use the 'attributes' option on the anchrome library in the following way.

```
var string = "mylink.com";
var result = anchorme(string,{
    attributes:[
        {
            name:"target",
            value:"_blank"
        },
    ]
});
console.log(result) // <a href="http://mylink.com"  target="_blank" >mylink.com</a>
```

Basically you need to add the attributes to have a `{ name:"target", value : "_blank"}`

for further reading : [Usage](http://alexcorvi.github.io/anchorme.js/#usgae)